# Laravel blade best practice to assign variable

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I do have simple conditions like this, what is the best practice to use within a laravel blade?

```
@if($revv < 25)
    <? $rv = 2; ?>
@elseif($revv >= 25 && $revv < 35)
    <? $rv = 2.5;?>
@elseif($revv >= 35 && $revv < 50)
    <? $rv = 3;?>
@else
    <? $rv = round($revv/20);?> 
@endif
```

Is above one is the best method when I can do the following with just 2 php tags,

```
<?php
    if($revv < 25){
        $rv = 2;
    }
    elseif($revv >= 25 && $revv < 35){
        $rv = 2.5;
    }elseif($revv >= 35 && $revv < 50){
        $rv = 3;
    }else{
        $rv = round($revv/20);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to do this in the controller or a separate helper function (depending on the actual use case). Besides that I'd do it the second way as you don't gain any advantage using `@if` if you're going to use PHP tags anyways...

Comment: You're welcome. If you need more help or want a more precise answer I'd need to know in what context you currently have this if statements (read: more code)